# Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined, when an object is passed. React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsobject

I want to send an "object" in firestore.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log(typeof(basketArray))
  addDoc(orderCollectionRef, {
    name: newName,
    email: newEmail,
    phone: newPhone,
    home: newHome,
    pinCode: newPinCode,
    city: newCity,
    state: newState,
    numberOfBooks: (basket.length),
    order: basket,
  }).then(makePayment)
}
```

The basket is an object.

I tried using
`Object.value(basket)`
`Object.entries(basket)`
`Object.key(basket)`
none of these worked.

Comment: Are you sure all the data you are passing is valid? From the error it does not seem so.

Comment: Check all fields name and format of data that passing into your object.